# How to stay logged-in in windows phone 8 , c#?

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8

I wrote an application that allows a new user to sign in (using Azure).

When clicking on the Home button, and after some seconds  returning to the application (without logging out)  - I need to sign in again.

I want to allow the user the stay signed in. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: are you using single sign on with live id?

Comment: No, I using regular sign in with internal calss that includes all needed users data